# How to check for an element in the rest of a the list in python?

Tags: python, list, arraylist

My list goes like this:

[1,2,1,2,1,1,2,2,1]

I want to go through the list. Every time I find a 1 in the list, I want to look for the 2 that comes after it.
If there's a 2, then I want to delete both the 1 and that particular 2.
This process continues for all 1s in the list

At the end, here I should be left with the last 1, that's it

How do I do this using python?

Comment: It's unclear whether or not the code should iterate

Comment: It should use iteration. I'll modify the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply translate your description into Python code:

```
>>> lst = [1,2,1,2,1,1,2,2,1]
>>> res = []
>>> for elem in lst:
...     if res and res[-1] == 1 and elem == 2:
...         res.pop()        
...     else:
...         res.append(elem)
...
>>> res
[1]
```

Comment: Here what is meant by 'if res'?

Comment: @Prerk `if res` is a shortcut to check whether `res` is empty. `res[-1]` is used to get the last element of `res`. It seems that you lack a basic understanding of Python. You should read some introductory tutorials first.

Comment: Okay, I'll do that